# Looking for suggestions about what to try and fix on my tecumseh snow blower engine that stalls after you stop putting load on it

Tags: engine, small-engine, snowblower

I have a troy bilt snow blower with a tecumseh engine and it starts great and runs great. Most of the time, anyway. It will scoop up snow and throw it just fine, and then for no obvious reason it stalls. If I leave it idling with no load it runs fine endlessly.

If I put load on it (engage the augur or the wheel drive) then stop, after 5-10 seconds after I stop it will stall. I've replaced the spark plug, I've taken apart the carb, cleaned it,  cleaned out the jets. I don't know what else it could be.

When it's about to stall, if I pump the primer it will catch and start running fine again until I put some load on it and relieve the load again. Sometimes the same trick works by closing the choke, but I have to be quick and often miss it and it stalls.

If anybody has any suggestions of things to try to fix it, I'd appreciate it.

Not sure if this is exactly the right forum, but it says 'mechanics' not 'cars' specifically.

Answer (score 6):

I dumped a lot of fuel stabilizer and lots of this other blue enzyme stuff in the fuel tank and when I used it for this most recent snow, it never hiccuped. I guess it was bad gas.

Answer (score 2):

I've had luck running seafoam thru those snowblowers. Also, are you using very fresh gas? Does it happen when its fully warmed up?

Could it be an intake gasket leak?
Sometimes the carbs have to be replaced...How old is it?

Comment: Relatively fresh gas a few months old at most. yea, it happens cold or warm. Machine is about 3 years old. Intake before the carb? after the carb? I'm not a mechanical genius I just like to tinker and I'm cheap so I try and do it myself if I can.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same kind of issue last winter with my snow blower. I fix it by adjusting the carburator screw to allow more gas into the engine, now works like a charm.

Comment: I assume you mean on the carb?

Comment: @stu Yes, sorry.